# Splitting a string keeping some delimiters but removing another

Tags: java, regex

Basically I would like to split a string into an array delimiting by spaces and operators, but keep the operators while removing the spaces

ex. `3 52 9+- 2 3 * /`

will be `[3][52][9][+][-][2][3][*][/]`

Comment: After getting downvoted, I realized that you might have an arbitrary number of operators together.  Regex might not be the best tool for doing this.

Comment: yes I will.  What do you advise I do?

Comment: I restored my answer below.  It doesn't give your exact desired output, but it is close.

Comment: I'll just have to delete all elements that have space then... thanks

Comment: It appears that I have a working solution now, have a look below.

Comment: Oh wow thanks!  Yeah this is pretty confusing stuff for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic you want when splitting is to *consume* delimiters which are whitespace and to *not* consume delimiters which are arithmetic symbols.  Towards this end, we can use a lookahead to split by symbol, and use plain `\\s` to split by whitespace and remove it from the result.

```
String input = "3 52 9+- 2 3 * /";
input = input.replaceAll("([\\+\\-*/])(.)", " $1$2")
             .replaceAll("\\s+", " ");

String[] parts = input.split("(?<=[\+\-*/])|\\s")

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 52, 9, +,  -,  2, 3, *,  /]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "3 52 9+- 2 3 * /";
        input = input.replaceAll("([\\+\\-*/])", " $1 ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
        String[] parts = input.split("(?<=[+\\-*/ ])");
        List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String part : parts) {
            if(part.trim().length() > 0) {
                finalList.add(part);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(finalList);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[3 , 52 , 9 , +, -, 2 , 3 , *, /]
```

Comment: This looks a lot like my answer, and it also appears that your numbers have extra spaces appended to the end.

Comment: Yes , I already upvote your answer , there is the mistake on your code that I resolve it and answer it

Answer (score -1):

Try this regex:

```
([\-]?[^\s\+\-\*\/]+|[\+\-\*\/])
```

It will select:

`[\-]?` signed or unsigned

`[^\s\+\-\*\/]` characters that is neither spaces nor [+ - * /]

`or` `[\+\-\*\/]` [+ - * /]

Just match your case.